# Updated Android Studio - many errors now

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I was loading an old project into Android Studio. Android Studio asked to update which I allowed.

However - now I get error

> build failed  10s 30ms Run build  9s 822ms Load build 10ms Configure
>   build 413ms Calculate task graph  566ms Run tasks 8s 826ms null
>   C:/Users/my
>   name/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-28.0.0-alpha1.aar/24c78a15e89c609bfeae2b7928d5d678/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml
>   C:/Users/my
>   name/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-28.0.0-alpha1.aar/24c78a15e89c609bfeae2b7928d5d678/res/values-v28/values-v28.xml
>   W:/android-studio-projects/sharedid    C:/Users/my
>   name/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-28.0.0-alpha1.aar/24c78a15e89c609bfeae2b7928d5d678/res/values/values.xml   null    failed linking references.

"Run tasks" log is

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:processDebugResources'.     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>     at
>
> ...

In my

```
W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
```

file I have

```
<uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="14"
  android:targetSdkVersion="25"
/>
```

...

In my

```
W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build.gradle
```

file I have

```
compileSdkVersion 25
```

and

```
dependencies {
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    api 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.0.8'
}
```

also tried

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.0.8'
}
```

here is the whole file

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.example.customer.app"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion 25

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }

}

dependencies {
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    api 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.0.8'
}
```

...

My

```
W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\build.gradle
```

Looks like this

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
```

...

I am but lost on solving the Android Issues... Seems not to originate from my code but appcompat. Anyhow way to flush/fix this?

...

**UPDATE 23rd April:** I have made the following fixes

In W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
}
```

In W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
  applicationId "com.example.company.app"
  minSdkVersion 14
  compileSdkVersion 25
}
```

This resulted in a new set of errors - but I feel it is progress:

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:processDebugResources'.     at
>
> ...
>
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource
>   linking failed Output: 
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\src\main\res\drawable\layerlist_micratingstars.xml:3:
>   warn: generated id 'android:id/background' for external package
>   'android'.
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\src\main\res\drawable\layerlist_micratingstars.xml:5:
>   warn: generated id 'android:id/progress' for external package
>   'android'.
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\src\main\res\drawable\layerlist_micratingstars.xml:4:
>   warn: generated id 'android:id/secondaryProgress' for external package
>   'android'.
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v26\values-v26.xml:7:
>   error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v26\values-v26.xml:11:
>   error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v26\values-v26.xml:15:
>   error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not
>   found.
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7:
>   error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11:
>   error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:235:
>   error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:235:
>   error: resource android:attr/font not found.
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:235:
>   error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:235:
>   error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:235:
>   error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found. error: failed linking
>   references.
>
> Command:
>   C:\Users\%Username%.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-alpha11-4662957-windows.jar\fc4f56a13b0b656fb51bcc296aa62bd7\aapt2-3.2.0-alpha11-4662957-windows\aapt2.exe
>   link -I\
>           D:\Java-Android-SDK\platforms\android-25\android.jar\
>           --manifest\
>           W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
>           -o\
>           W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
>           -R\
>           @W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
>           --auto-add-overlay\
>           --java\
>           W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
>           --custom-package\
>           com.example.company.app\
>           -0\
>           apk\
>           --output-text-symbols\
>           W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
>           --no-version-vectors Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-alpha11-4662957-windows Daemon #0 Output: 
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\src\main\res\drawable\layerlist_micratingstars.xml:3:
>   AAPT: warn: generated id 'android:id/background' for external package
>   'android'.
>
> W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\src\main\res\drawable\layerlist_micratingstars.xml:5:
>   AAPT: warn: generated id 'android:id/progress' for external package
>   'android'.
>
> W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\src\main\res\drawable\layerlist_micratingstars.xml:4:
>   AAPT: warn: generated id 'android:id/secondaryProgress' for external
>   package 'android'.
>
> C:\Users\%UserName%.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0-alpha1.aar\19b5707f382b2fef8a056030a0107fe4\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:9:5-12:13:
>   AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
>
> C:\Users\%UserName%.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0-alpha1.aar\19b5707f382b2fef8a056030a0107fe4\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:13:5-16:13:
>   AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
>
> C:\Users\%UserName%.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0-alpha1.aar\19b5707f382b2fef8a056030a0107fe4\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:17:5-93:
>   AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster'
>   not found.
>
> C:\Users\%UserName%.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0-alpha1.aar\19b5707f382b2fef8a056030a0107fe4\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13:
>   AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
>
> W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11:
>   AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
>
> C:\Users\%UserName%.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0-alpha1.aar\19b5707f382b2fef8a056030a0107fe4\res\values\values.xml:148:5-153:84:
>   AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.
>
> C:\Users\%UserName%.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0-alpha1.aar\19b5707f382b2fef8a056030a0107fe4\res\values\values.xml:148:5-153:84:
>   AAPT: error: resource android:attr/font not found.
>
> C:\Users\%UserName%.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0-alpha1.aar\19b5707f382b2fef8a056030a0107fe4\res\values\values.xml:148:5-153:84:
>   AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.
>        C:\Users\%UserName%.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0-alpha1.aar\19b5707f382b2fef8a056030a0107fe4\res\values\values.xml:148:5-153:84:
>   AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>        C:\Users\%UserName%.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0-alpha1.aar\19b5707f382b2fef8a056030a0107fe4\res\values\values.xml:148:5-153:84:
>   AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
>        error: failed linking references. Command: C:\Users\%UserName%.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-alpha11-4662957-windows.jar\fc4f56a13b0b656fb51bcc296aa62bd7\aapt2-3.2.0-alpha11-4662957-windows\aapt2.exe
>   link -I\
>           D:\Java-Android-SDK\platforms\android-25\android.jar\
>           --manifest\
>           W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
>           -o\
>           W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
>           -R\
>           @W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
>           --auto-add-overlay\
>           --java\
>           W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
>           --custom-package\
>           com.example.company.app\
>           -0\
>           apk\
>           --output-text-symbols\
>           W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
>           --no-version-vectors Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-alpha11-4662957-windows Daemon #0     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:97)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteLinkException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:73)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:519)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:269)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
>     ... 33 more Caused by:
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource
>   linking failed Output: 
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\src\main\res\drawable\layerlist_micratingstars.xml:3:
>   warn: generated id 'android:id/background' for external package
>   'android'.
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\src\main\res\drawable\layerlist_micratingstars.xml:5:
>   warn: generated id 'android:id/progress' for external package
>   'android'.
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\src\main\res\drawable\layerlist_micratingstars.xml:4:
>   warn: generated id 'android:id/secondaryProgress' for external package
>   'android'.
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v26\values-v26.xml:7:
>   error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v26\values-v26.xml:11:
>   error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v26\values-v26.xml:15:
>   error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not
>   found.
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7:
>   error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11:
>   error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:235:
>   error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:235:
>   error: resource android:attr/font not found.
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:235:
>   error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:235:
>   error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>   W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:235:
>   error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found. error: failed linking
>   references.
>
> Command:
>   C:\Users\%UserName%.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-alpha11-4662957-windows.jar\fc4f56a13b0b656fb51bcc296aa62bd7\aapt2-3.2.0-alpha11-4662957-windows\aapt2.exe
>   link -I\
>           D:\Java-Android-SDK\platforms\android-25\android.jar\
>           --manifest\
>           W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
>           -o\
>           W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
>           -R\
>           @W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
>           --auto-add-overlay\
>           --java\
>           W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
>           --custom-package\
>           com.example.company.app\
>           -0\
>           apk\
>           --output-text-symbols\
>           W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
>           --no-version-vectors Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-alpha11-4662957-windows Daemon #0     at
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.doLink(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:177)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.link(Aapt2Daemon.kt:103)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.link(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:176)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:811)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:517)
>     ... 50 more

Comment: Which version of android studio are you using ? Can you put your app's build.gradle ? It is weird that you are using compileSdkVersion 25 where the app support tries to use libs for Android P (28)

Comment: Updated to version 3.0 of Android Studio -- maybe I should not have, but my experience that the longer I wait updating the more errors I get when I finally do

Comment: Did you tried to revert all `implementation` and `api` to `compile`

Comment: I have tried them all - same result.

Comment: @xiaomi I do not get it either :( Do let me know if there is anymore information you may need.

Comment: @Tom When you update Android Studio (I guess from 2.3 in your case), it requires to change few elements into your 2 `build.gradle` files. In order to help you, please edit your question with these 2 files. (Into your project folder and your app folder).

Comment: @xiamo Done - I have posted both now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

---> You don't need add

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="25"
/>
```

2. W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\app\build.gradle

   ```
   android {
   compileSdkVersion 27
   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.example.customer.app"
       minSdkVersion 15
       targetSdkVersion 27
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled true
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
   repositories {
       maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
   }
   }

   dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
   implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.0.8'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
   }
   ```
3. W:\android-studio-projects\sharedid\build.gradle

   ```
   buildscript {

   repositories {
       google()
       maven {
           url 'https://maven.google.com/'
           name 'Google'
       }
       jcenter()
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'

       // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
       // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
   }

   allprojects {
   repositories {
       google()
       maven {
           url 'https://maven.google.com/'
           name 'Google'
       }
       jcenter()
   }
   }

   task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
   }
   ```

You can try it.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. And thank you to everyone who tried to help. As a "jack of all trades" it is sometimes almost like starting over when returning 1½ year later to my old app projects.

Answer (score 1):

In build.graddle(app)

try changing dependencies

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying - does not seem to have solved the issue - but I have added your code to my SO post and upvoted your answer

Answer (score 1):

1. GoTO File>Project Structure(ctrl+ALT+Shift+S)
2. Click second button(Project) and change grade version to 4.4

Comment: It is already set to version 4.4 - but I will still upvote answer. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: I changed this in gradle file which means I think I made progess, but still have problems. I will update post.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the gradle  from the project and let android studio make one

Comment: I changed this in gradle file which means I think I made progess, but still have problems. I will update post.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the issue by updating the compileSdk version and build gradle  of the app.
First update the build tool version of the app to 3.1.1

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
}
```

Second change the compileSdkVersion version of the app.Two ways to update compileSdkVersion is:

1.Specify the buildToolVersion

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.robosoft.sampleproject"
    minSdkVersion 14
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
}
```

2.If you dont specify build tool version increase the compilSdkVersion to 26 for gradle 3.1.1

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.robosoft.sampleproject"
    minSdkVersion 14
    compileSdkVersion 25
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you update Android Studio, it always ask to update your gradle version.

If you allow to update the gradle version, Your whole build files need to update like Api's and target version Which is difficult to track.

What you can do is first re import as new project and don't allow upgrade the gradle version and try to compile then if it is compiled successfully then update your gradle version related to new Android Studio.

Comment: @Farez I siad "yes" to everything when asked. But yes - something bad must have happened somewhere. I will try your suggestion

Comment: Just import clean copy and don't upgarde gradle, I had this issue earlier in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Although this already has an answer, this didn't work for me. For lot's of developers who might still facing this issue and are unable fix by any of the above mentioned work around. Please see, what worked for me.
I noticed that in gradle.properties file there are 2 new lines,

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Commenting these 2 in the gradle.properties made all my issues go away, and  a successful build.
I hope this helps to some of the developers finding the resolution.